# Is $A_{33}$ a unique subgroup of $A_{34}$ with index $34?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As $A_{33}$ is a unique subgroup of $S_{33}$ with index $2$ and $A_{33}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{33}$, then $A_{33}~{\rm char}~S_{33}$?

As $S_{33}$ is a unique subgroup of $S_{34}$ with index 34, then $S_{33}~{\rm char}~S_{34}?$

Now, we have $A_{33}~{\rm char}~S_{34}$, and $A_{33}$ is a normal subgroup of $A_{34}$, this a contradiction as $A_{34}$ is simple. There is something wrong in my proof. Can someone point out where is not right in my proof and give me a hint to the right answer? Thinks in advance!

Oh, $S_{33}~{\rm char}~S_{34}$, this is wrong.

Comment: Assuming that $A_{34}$ means the alternating group of degree $34$, it is a simple group, so how can it have $A_{33}$ as a normal subgroup? It is not true that $S_{33}$ is the unique subgroup of $S_{34}$ of index $34$, there are $34$ such subgroups, all conjugate.

Comment: @Derek Holt, Thank you! Yes, I am wrong, $S_{33}$ is not unique subgroup of $S_{34}$ of index 34.

Comment: Yes you have to be careful. Group theorists often say that there is a unique subgroup of some group with some properties, but they really mean a unique conjugacy class of such subgroups.